# borrar dd/mm/aaaa de un input type date

Tags: html

¿Hola a todos alguien sabe como borrar las letras que se ponen en el input type date , osea que se quede blanco como un input typo texto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]?

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahi en la imagen esta lo que necesito porfavor leanla.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar el código HTML de ese input. ¿Quizá tiene un atributo: `placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa"`? si lo tiene se lo eliminas y listo. Pero eso se puede poner también como valor por defecto, por CSS, etc. Convendría ver el HTML.

Comment: @A.Cedano puede que quiera mantener [el UI extendido y la validación del input tipo date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: También @aloMalbarez, pero nada podemos afirmar sin ver el código y sin conocer el contexto (navegador, versión, posibles librerías, etc).

Comment: lo que pasa es que necesito poner label sobre mis inputs pero no se ve bien en el de tipo date porque tiene el *dd/mm/aaaa*

Comment: Hola @JhonaJM, te recomiendo que pongas más información de lo que estés realizando para ayudarte. Realmente dejas una pregunta muy general y estaríamos realizando suposiciones frente a tu pregunta., puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) de la comunidad.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes aplicarse javascript usando la siguiente sentencia

```
document.getElementById('id de tu input).innerHtml = "";
```

Otra forma usando javascript, es usando el name del input

```
document.getElementByName('name asociado a tu input).innerHtml ="";
```

Tambien se puede hacer por jquery

```
$("#id del input").val("");
```

Otra opcion, que se me ocurre sin tener que programar es borrar el placeholder del elemento html
Espero ser de ayuda, saludos

Answer (score 2):

puedes remover el elemento de placeholder de tu input tipo date

```
<style>
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field:not([aria-valuenow]),
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field:not([aria-valuenow]) {
color: transparent;
}
</style>
<input type=date>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no quitárselo mejor, en caso de que lo tuviera? ¿Se justifica en este caso ponerle un atributo al elemento para luego quitárselo por CSS porque no se quiere que ese elemento tenga ese atributo?

Comment: @Danitza Ayala no me funciona ese codigo

Answer (score 2):

El efecto para realizar eso se llama "placeholder" que básicamente asigna un texto falso al input.

```html
<input type="text"; placeholder="Fecha Doc."></input>
```

Comment: crees que no lo he probado? eso es algo muy basico como para olvidarlo, no funciona porque es tipo DATE, de todas maneras gracias por intentar ayudar

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!
Dejo una respuesta a esta pregunta aunque haya pasado tanto tiempo por si alguien la esta buscando.

Si se desea que el campo quede totalmente vacio (sin texto placeholder):
   -No funciona `placeholder = ""`.

-Una opción es hacerlo un input `type="text"`con js cuando se lo enfoca pasarlo a `type=date` y cuando pierde el foco devolverlo a `type="text"`
Referencia: [Cambiar placeholder en type date](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/255321/cambiar-placeholder-en-type-date)

- La opción que yo uso es con CSS agrego un placeholder de espacios vacios antes del "DD/MM/YYYY" y configuro `white-space: pre;
- Luego necesito que al enfocarse se vea bien por lo que pongo el `content: "" !important;`
- Finalmente necesito que al anotar una fecha no se oculte por lo que con js hago un onchange=white-space: pre;

  -Yo uso jquery para hacero generico a todos mis date pero podes usar varias formas hasta la no recomendada onchange en la etiqueta del date.

La contra de este método es que el input tiene que tener un ancho fijo.

```js
  // Cuando cambia un input date me borra los espacios
  $('[type=date]').change( function() {
    $(this).css('white-space','normal')
  });
```

```css
  /* Hago que el navegador no me reemplace los espacios en blanco por uno solo */
  input[type="date"]{
   width:400px;
   white-space: pre;
  }
  /* placeholder de espacios en blanco */
  input[type="date"]::before{
   content: attr(placeholder) "                                                                        ";
  }
  /* Cuando se enfoca que no esten los espacios en blanco */
  input[type="date"]:focus::before {
     content: "" !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" name="birthday">
```

Saludos