# Cambiar placeholder en type date

Tags: php, javascript

Resulta que tengo un formulario el mismo se llama formulario.php donde tengo dos campos(input) que son fechas por lo tanto son type=date y no me dejaba cambiarle el placeholder porque siempre me fijaba en el valor de placeholder el tipo de dato de fecha.
Con una función logre cambiarlo y que aparezca el placeholder pero mi problema es que el placeholder no aparece desde el momento que la pagina carga, si no que hay que pararse dentro del campo(input) de fecha.

Les dejo la funcion que uso:

```
<input class="input100"  type="date" name="nacimientotitular" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento del Titular" onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```

En resumen lo que quiero es que cuando inicio la pagina de formulario, mi campo de fecha en vez de mostrar el tipo de dato de fecha (mm-dd-yyyy) muestre el placerholder("Fecha de Nacimiento")

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta, ¿podrías explicarte mejor? Pulsa [edit] para mejorar la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: Ahí edité, espero que se entienda un poco mejor. Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, al momento de que cargue la página el `input type date` lo cambiarás por tipo `texto`, y cuando obtenga el *foco* por un tipo `date` y cuando pierda el *foco* nuevamente por tipo `text`, le agregue un `id` para que lo puedas seleccionar por el mismo, espero te funcione. :D

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

document.getElementById('fecha').type= 'text';

document.getElementById('fecha').addEventListener('blur',function(){

document.getElementById('fecha').type= 'text';

});

document.getElementById('fecha').addEventListener('focus',function(){

document.getElementById('fecha').type= 'date';

});

});
```

```html
<body>

<input id="fecha" class="input100"  type="date" name="nacimientotitular" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento del Titular">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes inicializar el input como type="text", y te lo mostrara al cargar la página:

```
<input class="input100"  type="text" name="nacimientotitular" placeholder="Fecha de Nacimiento del Titular" onclick="ocultarError();" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```